# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET local IIS website odata error

Tags: iis, .net-core, odata

I have a web api application (net core 2.1.1) with odata protocol.

Everything works fine in Visual Studio 2017 (response is ok over https), but after I've deployed it to my local IIS website (with https binding), I have a ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 200 in Chrome using get request like https://localhost:5001/odata/Products.

Comment: Analyze bindings https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html as well as certificate, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Comment: Thanks. I'll into it and let you know.